# Regex to remove the specific word from URL

Tags: regex, dynatrace

In Dynatrace, there are the URLs which are containing the a word which is dynamic. Want to remove that dynamic word from the URL using regex

Below are the different urls

- /aaa/fdsadx/drtyu/**ab_cd**/myword?Id=953
- /asd/XXXXX/sadsa/two/**xx_yy**?Id=953
- /asd/fdsadx/df/three/**pp_qq**/myword
- /asd/fdsadx/sadsa/**ab_cd**
- /SSS/fdsadx/cvnm/forth/**gg_hh**

**Expected output**

- /asd/fdsadx/sadsa//myword?Id=953
- /asd/fdsadx/sadsa/?Id=953
- /asd/fdsadx/sadsa//myword
- /asd/fdsadx/sadsa/

I'm able to manage this regex

**(\S+?)ab_cd(.*)**

But its not working for dynamics values and all URL.
How Can I improve the regex to to remove the dynamic value?

Comment: it's not clear what you are basing which part is "dynamic" on.. to me anyway... do you just want to remove the part of the path with an underscore in the middle of letters?

Comment: Can there be an underscore before the `ab_cd/` part?

Comment: The bold characters are dynamic one. Basically it is (Language Code_Country Code)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use the 2 capturing groups and match the underscore part after matching a forward slash

```
^(\S+/)[^\s_]+_[^\s_/?]+(.*)
```

- `^` Start of string
- `(\S+/)` Capture **group 1**, match 1+ times a non whitespace char followed by `/`
- `[^\s_]+` Match 1+ times any char except a whitespace char or `_`
- `_` Match literally
- `[^\s_/?]+` Match 1+ times any char except a whitespace char,  `_`, `/` or `?`
- `(.*)` Capture **group 2** Match 0+ times any char except a newline

[Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/cQsWbp/1)

In the replacement use the 2 capturing groups, for example `$1$2`

If you want to match country codes and you know that they for example consist of chars a-zA-Z you could make the [character class](https://www.regular-expressions.info/charclass.html) more specific

```
^(\S+/)[A-Za-z]+_[A-Za-z]+(.*)
```

[Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/81sgpz/1)

Answer (score 1):

It seems that the first portion is fixed, and you're trimming everything after a '/' or '?'. Given that, perhaps you want something like:

`s/(\/asd\/fdsadx\/sadsa\/)[^/?]+(.*)/\1\2/`

This will capture the head in \1, ignore a group of characters that are not either '\' or '?', and capture the tail in \2.

Comment: No first part is also varies like

/aaa/fdsadx/drtyu/ab_cd/myword?Id=953
/asd/XXXXX/sadsa/two/xx_yy?Id=953
/asd/fdsadx/df/three/pp_qq/myword
/SSS/fdsadx/cvnm/forth/ab_cd